# If $d\mid e$, does the ideal $(x^d-1, 1+x+\cdots+x^{e-1})\subset\mathbb{Z}[x]$ contain $1+x+\cdots x^{d-1}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> If $d\mid e$, does the ideal $(x^d-1, 1+x+\cdots+x^{e-1})\subset\mathbb{Z}[x]$ contain $1+x+\cdots+x^{d-1}$?

For an integer $n$, let $\chi_n(X) := 1+X+\cdots+X^{n-1}$.

Certainly $\chi_d(x)$ divides both $x^d-1$ and $\chi_e(x)$. Moreover, the quotient $\chi_e(x)/\chi_d(x)$ is coprime to $(x^d-1)/\chi_d(x)$.

Since the polynomials involved are all primitive, I feel like some form of Gauss's lemma should imply the result, but I'm not sure.

Comment: For example if $d=2,e=4$, then the ideal $\langle x^2-1, x^3+x^2+x+1 \rangle$ is contained in the kernel of the morphism $\mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z} / 4\mathbb{Z}, x \mapsto 1$ whereas $x+1$ is not in this kernel.

Comment: Generalizing the above. Just note that $\chi_e=\chi_{e-d}(X^d-1)+\chi_{e-d}+\chi_d$. Now, let $e=qd$, and one can show, through induction, $\chi_e=(\chi_{(q-1)d}+\cdots+\chi_{d})(X^d-1)+q\chi_d$. So one sees that in general $(\chi_{qd},X^d-1)=(q\chi_d,X^d-1)=(\chi_d)(q,X+1)$, which can only equal $(\chi_d)$ if $q=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simple counterexample, let $d=1$ and $e=2$.

Note that when $d=1$, the expression
$$1+x+\cdots+x^{d-1}$$
is presumably intended to be equal to $1$, not $2$.

Then in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, the ideal $(x-1,x+1)$ does not contain $1$.

Suppose instead that
$$a(x)(x-1)+b(x)(x+1)=1$$
for some $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Now plug in $x=1$, and note that the $\text{LHS}$ is divisible by $2$, while the $\text{RHS}$ is equal to $1$.

$\qquad\overline{
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
}
$

More generally, let $d,e$ be any positive integers such that $d < e$.

If we suppose that in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, the polynomial
$$1+x + \cdots + x^{d-1}$$
is an element of the ideal
$$(x^d-1,1+x + \cdots + x^{e-1})$$
we would have
$$a(x)(x^d-1)+b(x)(1+x + \cdots + x^{e-1})=1+x + \cdots + x^{d-1}$$
for some $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.

But then if we plug in $x=1$, the $\text{LHS}$ is divisible by $e$, while the $\text{RHS}$ is equal to $d$.

Comment: 4 doesn't divide 2.

Comment: I haven't been following closely, but it seems you have changed earlier incorrect answers into the answer given long ago in a comment. At the least you should acknowledge DS's prior comment

Comment: Actually, I didn't look at the comments to the OP.

Comment: Fixed! In my original comments I miscomputed $\chi_1$ as $0$. That was my mistake. So $+1$.